# Can't make my bootstrap 3 javascript to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I downloaded bootstrap 3.0.0, but I can't get my navbar dropdown to work... Also tried to include dropdown.js, but it just doesn't work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">

    </div>
    <script src="bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help...

- Becouse I can't submit my question(too much code), so I'm writing this random text to keep the balance between code and the details about it.

Comment: Can you add every HTML code related to your `navbar` please ? (`navbar-header`, `navbar-collapse`, `navbar-nav`... etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance I would say that the script tag you use for importing bootstrap should not use href, you should use it like the jquery one.
`<script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`
They are as far as I know not interchangeable.

After I made that change to your file the dropdown worked for me.

Comment: Omg an hour struggle for this ... Thank you :))!